# How can i update a page without reloading with Ajax and Django Rest Framework?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

In my Django project, i'm trying to create a page where some data is uploaded in real time, without reloading the whole page.

That data is retrieved from a database, so i created an API endpoint with Django Rest Framework, the problem is that i don't know how to go from here.

I already know that, to update the page, i'll need to use Ajax. But i don't know how to create the Ajax part. I think that i need to add a `POST` request in my template, but that's all i know for now. Can someone give me some direction on where to go from here? Any advice is appreciated

Basically the Ajax request should call the endpoint, which is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst/`, and update the data every `X` (something between 1 and 5 seconds).

**serializers.py**

```
class tstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = tst
        fields = ('ticker', 'Price', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return tst.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**views.py**

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer


class tstDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.using('screener').all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
```

**template.html**

```
<h3>Here will be a table with the data uploaded in real time..</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, basically the collection i wanted to use is called `tst`. When i created the model `tst` in my Django project, instead of using the already existing collection called `tst`, it created a new collection called `main_tst` (main is the name of the project). So the data is being retrieved from `main_tst` and not `main`.